# Problems with number inputs on discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I am having issues with a timer command in discord.js. I'd like to check if the user inputted a valid time as an argument:

```js
case 'timer':
  let time = args[1];
  if(!time) {
    return message.reply("<:what:784258557067526174> Please specify a time!");
  }
  message.reply(`Timer started for ${ms(ms(time))}`)

  setTimeout(function(){
    message.reply('your timer has ended')
  }, ms(time));
  break;
```

The way the code is supposed to work is seen in the first example in the image. If the user type the command with a valid time, the bot starts a timer and responds with "Timer started for %time%".

But I want it to respond with a certain message if an invalid input is entered, as seen in the second example in the image:

[image]

Comment: You have to verify whether your arguments are fit to your proposed format. And after determining whether it fits or not you can reply with an error message.

Comment: Why are you calling `ms()` twice inside eachother?`

Comment: The first `ms()` converts to milliseconds, the second one converts back to human readable format.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
if (!/^\d+m$/.test(time)) {
    return message.reply("Invalid time")
}
```

Here, I use a regular expression to make sure time is a series of digits (`\d+`) followed by the literal character m. If not you can send a message with a error.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the [`ms` npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ms), you should know how it works. If you provide an invalid argument, it either throws an error, or returns `undefined`:

```js
const ms = require("ms")

console.log(ms('2h'))
// => 7200000

console.log(ms('10 ways'))
// => undefined

console.log(ms(' '))
// => undefined

console.log(ms(''))
// => throws an error 
// Error: val is not a non-empty string or a valid number.

console.log(ms(undefined))
// => throws an error
// Error: val is not a non-empty string or a valid number.
```

It means you can use a try-catch block to check if it's a valid input, if `ms` throws an error, the code in the `catch` block runs. If `ms` can't convert the argument to milliseconds, it returns `undefined`, you can send an error message. See the snippet below:

```js
case 'timer':
  let time = args[1];

  // try to convert the time
  try {
    const timeInMilliseconds = ms(time);

    // if argument can't be converted to milliseconds
    if (!timeInMilliseconds) {
     return message.reply("<:what:784258557067526174> Please specify a time!");
    }

    // the rest of the code only runs if timeInMilliseconds exists
    setTimeout(function(){
      message.reply('your timer has ended')
    }, timeInMilliseconds);

    message.reply(`Timer started for ${ms(timeInMilliseconds)}`);
  } catch(err) {
    message.reply("<:what:784258557067526174> Please specify a time!");
  }

  break;
```

PS: Make sure you also set a maximum time the user can set. If you want to accept timers for a month, it won't work this way. In JavaScript, if you set the delay in `setTimeout` more than `Math.pow(2, 32)/2 - 1`, it will run immediately. I know it seems like a big number, but it's only ~25days.